# is it possible to assign multiple values after initalization within curly braces?

Tags: c#, syntax, operators, curly-braces

When creating an instance, you can specify all the member values within curly braces.

Is there a syntax that allows you to specify multiple value changes using the curly braces after it's already initialized.

Instead of using the member access operator `.`?

```
        // Create an instance
        var myForm = new Form
        {
            Left = 123,
            Text = "foo",
            AllowDrop = false
        };

        // Then if you want to change the members, you would specify them individually
        myForm.Left = 555;
        myForm.Text = "fee";
        myForm.AllowDrop = true;

        // Is there something that allows me to specify all the members
        // I want to change within curly braces again? i.e.
        myForm = 
        {
            Left = 123,
            Text = "foo",
            AllowDrop = false
        };
```

Comment: The following may be helpful [Object and Collection Initializers (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers) and [initializer](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/initializer)

Comment: @user9938 Can you point to the specific part that's useful here?

Comment: No, there's not - what benefit do you see from that syntax over using the property setters?

Comment: The answer is "no". As the link provided above suggests, that first syntax is called an "object initialiser". As the name suggests, it is for initialising an object. It cannot be used after initialisation.

Comment: @DStanley for something shorthand like this `doTask(foo.Clone(){ optionToChange: 123 });`

Comment: In VB there is the `With` keyword that allows you to do something like that, so much so that `With` is used in the VB syntax for object initialisers. There is no C# equivalent.

Comment: That's actually a good example :) unfortunately there's not a construct in C# for that. The cleanest thing I can think of is creating a "copy constructor" or factory method.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar: The repeated use of the word "initializer". I've added a link to a dictionary definition for those who English may be a second language.

Comment: @DStanley ok, just wanted to know if it existed and I just happened to not find it via google.

Comment: Also relevant https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/with-expression

Comment: @Charlieface neat and good to know

Answer (score 0):

It's not a direct `=` but it's as close as I can seem to manage.

```
myForm = myForm.With(new
{
     Left = 123,
     Text = "foo",
     AllowDrop = false
});
```

...where `With` is an extension that takes an anonymous collection initializer as its argument and uses reflection to iterate it, copying  the new values from that new object to the existing properties of `this T`. Returning `@this` *as* `T` is what makes chaining work correctly. It can be called similar to what you show in your comment:

```
doTask(foo.With(new {Location = point, Text = "fee", BackColor = color }));
```

*or*

```
doTask(foo.Clone().With(new { Location = point, Text = $"Fee {_tstCount++}", BackColor = color }), isClone: true);
```

---

**Extension**

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static T With<T>(this T @this, object anon)
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        foreach (var propSrce in anon.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var propDest = type.GetProperty(propSrce.Name);
            if (propDest == null)
            {
                Debug.Assert(false, $"Property '{propSrce}' not found in {type.Name}");
            }
            else
            {
                propDest.SetValue(@this, propSrce.GetValue(anon));
            }
        }
        return @this;
    }
}
```

---

**TEST**

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm() => InitializeComponent();

    static int _tstCount = 1;
    private void buttonTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Generate some test values
        var point = new Point(Location.X + 25, Location.Y);
        Color color;
        switch (_tstCount % 3)
        {
            case 0:
                color = Color.LightBlue;
                break;
            case 1:
                color = Color.LightGreen;
                break;
            default:
                color = SystemColors.Control;
                break;
        }
        // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        // TEST
        var foo = this;
        doTask(foo.With(new { Location = point, Text = $"Fee {_tstCount++}", BackColor = color }));
    }
    private void doTask(MainForm form, bool isClone = false)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(form.Location);
        Debug.WriteLine(form.Text);
        Debug.WriteLine(form.BackColor);
        Debug.WriteLine(String.Empty);

        if (isClone)
        {
            if (!form.Visible) form.Show();
            Debug.Assert(
                !ReferenceEquals(this, form),
                "Expecting CLONED instance with NEW values.");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Assert(
                ReferenceEquals(this, form),
                "Expecting SAME instance with NEW values.");
        }
    }
}
```

[image: form doTask]

[image: debug console]

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/reassign-properties-within-curly-braces.git)